# JavaScript Best Practices - Global Variables

Tags: javascript, performance

Can anyone provide feedback on how i can improve the script below? The script does work properly but uses Global Variables, I've been told that the use of global variables can cause issues in code.

```
    var vehicle = document.getElementById('vehicle');
    var residence = document.getElementById('residence');

    vehicle.setAttribute("class", "hide");

    document.getElementById('myList').addEventListener('change', function(){
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.forms'), function(e){
            e.setAttribute("class", "hide");
        });

        var sel=+this.selectedIndex - 2;
        if(sel >= 0){
            vehicle.setAttribute("class", "show");
            residence.setAttribute("class", "hide");
        } else {
            residence.setAttribute("class", "show");
            vehicle.setAttribute("class", "hide");
        }
    });
```

Comment: depends, how is this code being used? What is the application? If there is something you don't want your users snooping into you should look into minifying your javascript code.

Comment: Why are you using `e.setAttribute("class", "hide");` instead of `e.className = "hide";`?

Comment: @Mike Minifying really doesn't help that much in terms of hiding content from users. Simply copy the code and paste it into an _"unminifier"_ such as [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/), and your code is fully readable again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use a function for privacy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){

    var vehicle = document.getElementById('vehicle');
    var residence = document.getElementById('residence');

    vehicle.setAttribute("class", "hide");

    document.getElementById('myList').addEventListener('change', function(){
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.show'), function(e){
            e.setAttribute("class", "hide");
        });

        var sel=+this.selectedIndex - 2;
        if(sel >= 0){
            vehicle.setAttribute("class", "show");
        } else {
            residence.setAttribute("class", "show");
        }
    });

})();
</script>
```

doesn't get much easier: you don't need to alter your written code at all, just wrap it up.

Comment: @War10ck why? and @dandavis if you want to improve this script at first you should change `vehicle.setAttribute("class", "hide");` to `vehicle.className = "hide";` and than instead of `Array.prototype.forEach.call` you can simply use `[].forEach.call`, also get all variable declarations at the top, and add strict mode. ;)

Comment: i wanted to demonstrate the ease of implementing a wrapper function, and basically preserving the orig code (for better or worse) makes that simplicity crystal clear. Otherwise, it could be confusing what change actually helped.

Comment: @Givi It's the proper syntax. You're closing the anonymous function with this `})` and then immediately invoking it via a function call like `();` this. The way it was written originally should have thrown a syntax error.

Comment: @War10ck: no need to let those "dog balls" dangle at the bottom: the wrapper outer parens clue the reader into the self-contained functionality. It's not a syntax error by any means, and doug crockford recommends the style i used for readability.

Comment: @War10ck but JSLint throws error: `Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function.`

Comment: @Givi: yup, it's no surprise that doug's tool enforces his brutal readability guidelines...

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it makes easier to write a JavaScript code without errors.

Comment: @user1584751 Make sure that you have a look at my answer. Avoiding polluting the global namespace is a must, however there are other improvements that can be done.

Comment: @Givi JSLint is far too restrictive in my opinion. I tend to favor JSHint.

Comment: lint and hint are not for the same purpose. lint is for checking human code readability, hint is for checking machine code quality.

Answer (score 1):

It would be way better to modularize your code into testable and reusable components.

There are tons of ways to achieve this, but here's a simple example...

Define an object that represents your feature:

```
yourNS = window.yourNS || {};

yourNS.YourFeature = {
    init: function (options) {
        var vehiculeEl = document.querySelector(options.vehicleEl),
            residenceEl = document.querySelector(options.residenceEl),
            listEl = document.querySelector(options.listEl);

        vehiculeEl.className = 'hide';

        listEl.addEventListener('change', function () {

            var showVehicule = this.selectedIndex - 2 >= 0;

            vehiculeEl.className = showVehicule? 'show' : 'hide';
            residenceEl.className = showVehicule? 'hide' : 'show';
        });
    }
};
```

Use it:

```
!function () {
    yourNS.YourFeature.init({
        vehiculeEl: '#vehicule',
        residenceEl: '#residence',
        listEl: '#myList'
    });
}();
```

You might be interested by [Writing Testable JavaScript](http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript), written by Rebecca Murphey.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has it's own JS style, but I prefer using a global JS object that stores all my variables but this only where it is really needed.

```
var GLOBAL = 
{
    key:"value",
    key2:variable,
    key3:
    {
        key4:variable,
        key5:'hans'
    }
};
GLOBAL.key3.key5 = 'peter';
```

An other option is to use a function that does everything, so the variables you use are contained in the namespace of your function.

```
var foo = function()
{
    var iAmInvisible = 42;
}
```

Comment: who you calling "it"? ;)

Answer (score 0):

For global variables you can use object "window":

```
window.vehicle = { param1 : "abc", param2 : document.getElementById('idXYZ').value};  // It is not necessary "var"
```

to access the variable :

```
window.vehicle.param1
```